# Kendo UI Mobile Listview always display [object Object]

Tags: wcf, listview, kendo-mobile

I'm using Kendo UI Listview control to display Categories data from WCF Service. the problem is always the list view instead of displaying the "Name" of the Category, it display [object Object].

the Json Data returned from the service is like

d

```
               Items

                          ID=1

                          Name=Sports

                          IsActive=true
```

the HTML code:

```
<body>
<div data-role="view" data-init="mobileListViewPullWithEndless">
    <ul id="grouped-listview"></ul>
</div>
<script>
    var categoriesTransport = new kendo.data.RemoteTransport({
        read: {
            url: "http://localhost:11124/Services/PublishingMobileService.svc/GetAllCategories", //specify the URL which data should return the records. This is the Read method of the Products.svc service.
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", // tells the web service to serialize JSON
            dataType: 'json',
            type: "POST" //use HTTP POST request as the default GET is not allowed for svc
        },
        parameterMap: function (data, operation) {
            if (operation != "read") {
                // web service method parameters need to be send as JSON. The Create, Update and Destroy methods have a "products" parameter.
                return JSON.stringify(data);
            } else {
                return JSON.stringify(data);
            }
        }
    });
    function mobileListViewPullWithEndless(e) {
        $("#grouped-listview").kendoMobileListView({
            height: 400,
            dataSource:kendo.data.DataSource.create( {
                schema: {
                    data: "d.Items", // svc services return JSON in the following format { "d": <result> }. Specify how to get the result.                     
                },
                transport: categoriesTransport,
                template: $("#endless-scrolling-template").text(),
            }),
        });
    }
</script>
<script type="text/x-kendo-tmpl" id="endless-scrolling-template">
    <div>
        <h3>#:ID#</h3>
    </div>
</script>
<script>
    var app = new kendo.mobile.Application(document.body);
</script>
```

Could you please help on that.?

Answer (score 0):

I understand this question is a bit old, but for future reference:

I had this exact issue recently when I bound to an observable without a template. Adding the template as you have gave me the same issue, whereas adding like this works:

```
<ul id="accomodations-list" 
    data-role="listview" 
    data-style="inset"
    data-bind="source:accommodations"
    data-template="template"></ul>
```